# Godel's theorem incompleteness, truth vs.provability

Tags: logic, incompleteness, provability

I know this question has been investigated in other threads, but I would like to pose yet another question on Gödel's theorem incompleteness, and  truth in 'the standard model' compared with provability in the 'formal model'.

I will use the language of Gensler's little book "Gödel's Theorem Simplified" (see [here](http://kevincarmody.com/math/goedelgensler.pdf) for a summary).

For what Gensler calls System C, he gives an outline for how to construct a wff in system C. The system C the symbols are /, (, ), - , n (for a variable), nn (another variable),...etc.).

The reference numbers for system C formulas (like Godel numbers) are defined too.

For example the ref # for / is 1, the reference # for the variable n is 8, etc.

Then Gensler gives instructions for how to create a formula called F which states

(F) "There is no system C proof for the son of the system C formula with reference # n ".

Here n is a variable. So the system C formula with reference # n exists, call that system C formula XX, and F is the statement that the system C son of XX, SonXX, is not a theorem in system C).

F is a string of symbols of system C.The son of F is obtained by taking the reference number (an actual whole number like 112278 etc) for F, writing that whole number as the system C string //.../ (with reference # of F many /'s appearing) and replacing each occurrence the variable n in (F) with that many ///.../.

The result is a new system C formula, the son of F, called G.

The 'standard model' interpretation of G is then

(G) "There is no system C proof for the son of the system C formula with reference # equal to the reference # of F."

In other words, there is no system C proof of G itself.

Then Gensler and other sources indicate this standard interpretation of G is true, so it is a true 'ordinary arithmetic' statement, for which the corresponding system C formula has no proof.

It seems to me that what you can really say is this:

If you assume that the standard interpretation of G is a true statement in the ordinary standard model, then the corresponding system C formula is an unprovable system C formula. So you have a 'true' ordinary arith statement which cannot be proved in system C, BECAUSE you have ASSUMED that the standard model version of G is true.

If you assume that the standard interpretation of G is a false statement in the ordinary standard model, then the corresponding system C formula is an provable system C formula.So you have a 'false' ordinary arith statement which can be proved in system C, BECAUSE you have ASSUMED that the standard model version of G is false.

But how do you know that one of the two statements " G is a true statement in the ordinary standard model" or " G is a false statement in the ordinary standard model" must be valid?

Isn't the best you can say that IF you could determine that G were a true statement in the ordinary standard model" or " G is a false statement in the ordinary standard model" THEN you can draw conclusions about non provability or provability of G as a system C formula?

Comment: The assumption is a part of the theorem itself: Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem states that, for a model with sufficient "power" (can represent arithmetic), that its consistency implies its incompleteness. It stands to reason, then, that one would assume G to be true. If you wish to prove the opposite (that completeness implies inconsistency), then you would assume that a proof of G exists, thus rendering it false, and your model inconsistent. Now, the theorem does not actually require consistent as an assumption- weaker assumptions work- but that is the one your mentioned book uses.

Comment: You can see the lenghty post [Is PA consistent? do we know it?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66121/is-pa-consistent-do-we-know-it)

Comment: [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) is : "if [system] $C$ is *consistent*, then [formula] $G$ is *unprovable*". But also $\lnot G$ is *unprovable*. The two are *sentences* of $C$ and thus - for every model $\mathcal M$ of $C$ - exactly one of them (it does not matter what one) - **must** be TRUE in $\mathcal M$ .

Comment: Thanks for these two replies, which I do find helpful.

Comment: Here is the way they have helped me understand the theorem.

THE KEY IS THAT GODEL’S IMCOMPLETENESS THM SAYS IF A MODEL OF ARITH (LIKE THE STANDARD ONE) IS CONSISTENT THEN IT MUST BE INCOMPLETE.

IN THE GODEL/ GENSLER MODEL: ASSUME STANDARD ARITH IS CONSISTENT. IF IT IS ALSO COMPLETE THEN ONE OF THESE MUST BE TRUE:

" G is a true statement in the ordinary standard model" or " G is a false statement in the ordinary standard model"
(and consistency implies exactly 1 must be true). 
So consistency makes completeness impossible and completeness means 1 of these MUST be true.

Comment: Or perhaps stated more clearly: If the completeness assumption is in place then at least one of "G is true" or "G is false" (in the standard model) must be true. In this case either there are true ordinary arith statements which are not provable in the formal (system C) model, or there are false ordinary arith statements which are provable in the formal (system C) model.
So in either case we see that the formal system C model does not accurately determine what ordinary arith statements are true or false by virtue of the corresp. system C statements being provable or not provable.